# Basic calculator C++, there is no error but code only returns 0 regardless of the value

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to coding and I wanted to attempt a basic calculator after weeks of studying, however this code only returns the value of 0 regardless of the number or function input. 
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include<iostream>    
using namespace std;

int main(){     
    int number;
    int secNumber;
    int sum;
    string function;
    string add;
    string subtract;
    string divide;
    string modulus;
    string multiply;

    cout << "what will be your first number?" << endl;      
    cin >> number;

    cout << "what will be your second number?" << endl;     
    cin >> secNumber;

    cout << "what would you like to do with these number?" << endl;     
    cin >> function;

    if (function==add)          
        sum = number + secNumber;           
    else if (function==subtract)            
        sum = number - secNumber;           
    else if(function== divide)          
        sum = number/secNumber;         
    else if(function== multiply)            
        sum = number*secNumber;         
    else if(function==modulus)          
        sum = number%secNumber;

    cout << "Your sum is "<<sum << endl;
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: compare should be function == "add"  not function == add. the strings are not initialized.

Comment: Please try to make the title of your question a short summary of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not initializing `add`, `subtract`, etc. Those `string`s are all empty. So regardless of what function you're entering, they're not going to compare equal against an empty string.

Instead, compare against string literals:

```
if (function == "add") {
    sum = number + secNumber;
}
else if (function == "subtract") {
    ...
}
...
```

It would also be helpful to add an error message at the end, in case the user enters an invalid function:

```
else {
    std::cout << "Unknown function " << function;
}
```

Comment: A switch will be a better option with default throwing an exception of unmatched entry.

Comment: @SatishChalasani You can't `switch` a `string`

Comment: @SatishChalasani Thanks, well noted.

Comment: @Barry I mean using enums. You can define enum operation { add = 1, subtract, .. } and use these in switch.